# How to redirect from old link to new link in mvc

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

how can i redirect old link to new link in mvc

In google search result google cached my old url eg : www.abcd.com/product?id=64
but my new url is now eg : www.abcd.com/product/sample

when user click on old link in google result it will redirect to my new link

i created my project in mvc 4

Comment: If the link still works, then what's the problem?  What's in your RouteConfig to stop the old link working?  Sounds like you want a **302** not a 400/500 (500 is *not* Notfound, your web.config will cause issues in the future).  You could add a Route that matches with `?id=` as a literal which hits an action that returns a redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm Assuming that you never want www.abcd.com/product?id=64 to be the correct URL again -- i.e. this isn't a temporary change in your routing.

The first thing is that you need to make sure your controller method still accepts the request (i.e. the route config still routes the request to a controller method), but then instead of ending the controller method with:

```
return View(model);
```

It should end with:

```
return RedirectToActionPermanent("new action", "new controller");
```

Obviously, somehow you need to figure out where to redirect to in your controller method.

There are also RedirectPermanent and RedirectToRoutePermanent alternatives, and in all cases, it will cause browsers hitting that URL to redirect to where you want them, and also let the search crawlers know to update their tables/results.

You can use Redirect with the Permanent, but that will not tell the search engines to update anything.  They will keep crawling the old URLs.